# Meeting start/end timeZone are intermittently modified to UTC

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

When I use the graph api to set a new meeting event, the timezone for the start and end timezones are updated to UTC, but the time is left alone. For instance, the object being passed in to the graph API may look like this:

```
{
subject: "arg",
body: {contentType: "HTML", content: "arg"},
start: {dateTime: "2020-03-03T03:00:00", timeZone: "Pacific Standard Time"},
end: {dateTime: "2020-03-03T04:00:00", timeZone: "Pacific Standard Time"},
attendees: []
}
```

But the response I receive back looks like this:

(truncated)

```
{
originalStartTimeZone: "UTC",
originalEndTimeZone: "UTC",
start: {
  dateTime: "2020-03-03T03:00:00.0000000",
  timeZone: "UTC"
},
end: {
  dateTime: "2020-03-03T04:00:00.0000000",
  timeZone: "UTC"
}
}
```

However, I'm noticing that updating the event will correctly save it as the selected timezone. Anyone have any ideas on how I can force this or if this is an issue with the graph api?

Comment: I'm looking at Microsoft's docs, and it seems you're using the correct format, but I also see that sometimes they use `timezone` with all lowercase characters.  Does that make a difference for you?

Comment: Also apparently there are limitations on the timezones allowed; you can get a list from the recipient's server with these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-supportedtimezones?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Where did you find that they are using lower case `timezone` in places? That seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: In the Outlook docs, I think. That's cool, I didn't expect that to work.

Comment: Oops....nevermind. It was just a few entries that worked. Now it's back to saving it as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug. When making this change via fetch with the same object, it works consistently.

[GitHub Issue submitted](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/269).